# InvalidOperationException on CompleteAsync from Session Enabled Queue

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

```
Using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
```

I have a session enabled queue, and I want to subscribe to both the active queue and DLQ so that when my session messages are dead lettered, I can process those messages from DLQ.

I call `queueClient.RegisterSessionHandler` to subscribe to the main (active queue), and `queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler` to subscribe to DLQ. Then every time I receive a message from DLQ, I want to complete the message (to remove from the DLQ). However, when I try to complete, I get this exception:

```
Encountered exception in message processing context. Action: UserCallback. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver. 
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.<DisposeMessagesAsync>d__99.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.<RunOperation>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.<RunOperation>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.<CompleteAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Media.Stream.SubstrateReplication.Common.Azure.Messaging.Providers.BrokeredMessageBase`1.<CompleteAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Media.Stream.SubstrateReplication.Common.Azure.Messaging.Providers.ServiceBusProviderBase.<ProcessReceivedDeadLetterMessageAsync>d__17`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Media.Stream.SubstrateReplication.Common.Azure.Messaging.Providers.ServiceBusQueueProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<<OnMessageReceivedAsync>b__3>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageReceivePump.<MessageDispatchTask>d__13.MoveNext() File Name:C:\s\src\Common\Azure\Messaging\Providers\ExceptionHandler.cs Method Name:HandleExceptionAsync Line Number:35 Exception:
```

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@samuelhutama/net-core-azure-service-bus-send-and-receive-message-in-session-enabled-subscription-3f8ffecc47de) saying that CompleteAsync is only allowed for non-session subscription (I'm assuming the same thing applies for queue as well?). But.. why? I was able to complete messages just fine when I initially just registered my sessionHandler. Ever since I added `registerMessageHandler` to DLQ of the main queue, I get this error whenever I try to complete... :-(

So my question is... why am I getting this exception? What am I doing wrong?

Also another item, I think I am processing the same dead letter messages over and over, so my metrics (dead letter count) is greatly different from the one that azure portal provides. I have no idea what's happening, I don't know if same message is being added multiple times to DLQ or for some reason lock isn't working making multiple listeners process messages at the same time... has anyone experienced this?

Thank you!

Comment: Pls, provide some details, code example of `queueClient`creation and handlers registration.